# Mysql update-database System.FormatException

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I received an error when trying to use the update-database migration features with EntityFramework. I used this function very often without problems.
Here are my 2 problems classes:

```
public class Produit
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Upc { get; set; }

    public int? BinId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BinId")]
    public Bin Bin { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class Bin
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NoBin { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

```
    PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201907231929105_Initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201907231929105_Initial.
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateIndexOperation op)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.<.ctor>b__22_4(MigrationOperation op)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Update>b__d()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

The enable-migrations worked and add-migration work too.

I use the packages:
MySql.Data.EntityFramework   (8.0.17.0)
MySql.Data (8.0.17.0)

Comment: That part in the error where it suggests you "Specify the '-Verbose' flag" ... you should do that.

Comment: -Verbose, I tried, but doesn't helped me... but Thank

Comment: But you get more info in the error log, yes?

Comment: The only information I had was that the connection to the database was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks the same as [bug 92561](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92561) in MySql.Data.EntityFramework, which is caused by running in a non-US-English locale.

As a workaround, you could try switching your computer's locale to U.S. English to run the migration.

Alternatively, try switching to [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql), an OSS implementation of EF Core for MySQL; a lot of people have reported that it's less buggy than Oracle's version.

Comment: Thank you!! I turn my computer into US English and everything works perfectly. I don't know why I do not find the Mysql bug before.